# Регулярные выражения. Разрешить пробел

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код, который разрешает русские и английские буквы

```
 if(!preg_match('#^([A-zА-я \-]*)$#ui', $_POST['name']))
```

мне нужно чтоб еще разрешало использовать пробел. 
Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Вы его уже разрешили :)  https://www.regex101.com/r/nH1tQ3/1

Answer (score 4):

if(!preg_match('#^([ёЁ\sA-zА-я -]*)$#ui', $_POST['name']))

Шпаргалка на регулярные выражения: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjdjx.png